# Replace html entities with PHPWord setValue function

Tags: javascript, php, xml, codeigniter, phpword

I have a problem with setValue() function in PHPWord. Normally, the parameter should be a plain text variable, but in this case I have to deal with a html block. And PHPWord cannot parse the html tag to word xml.

I mean to replace this html:
[image]

into the Word template:
[image]

To make the output like this:
[image]

Is there any solution?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -2):

You can use utf8_decode or htmlentities functions before set the var.
For example:

```
$document->setValue('cif', utf8_decode($cif));
$document->setValue('cif', htmlentities($cif));
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?